# What does the minimal number of round of "nr" use Keccak to avoid “collision attack”?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-3, keccak

What does the minimal number of round of "nr" use Keccak to avoid *collision attack*?

$$nr = 12+2L$$

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. I've edited your question. Please check, there are still some points. The Collision attack is inevitable. You should give a probability bound to achieve. See the birthday attack or [Sweet32](https://sweet32.info/)

Comment: @kelalaka How is sweet32 relevant?  There are standard costs widely understood to be unachievable; when a collision attack on a widely used unkeyed hash function at a reasonable length is achievable _once_ it is usually bad news for everyone, so there's not much sense in asking about specific probability bounds in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Cursory literature search suggests that the best collision attacks reach only six rounds of Keccak:

- Kexin Qiao, Ling Song, Meicheng Liu, and Jian Guo, ‘New Collision Attacks on Round-Reduced Keccak’, in Jean-Sébastien Coron and Jesper Buus Nielsen, eds., Advances in Cryptology—EUROCRYPT 2017, April 2017, Springer LNCS 10212, pp. 217–243 ([link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-56617-7), [preprint](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/128))
- Ling Song, Guohong Liao, and Jian Guo, ‘Non-full Sbox Linearization: Applications to Collision Attacks on Round-Reduced Keccak’, in Jonathan Katz and Hovav Shacham, eds., Advances in Cryptology—CRYPTO 2017, Part II, Springer LNCS 10402, August 2017, pp. 428–45 ([link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-63715-0_15), [preprint](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/529))

Of course, attacks only get better, so it would be imprudent to choose six rounds. 
 This state of affairs justified the use of a mere twelve rounds in [KangarooTwelve](https://keccak.team/kangarootwelve.html) at substantial speed increase over the twenty-four used by SHA-3.